# Print out keys and values of a map

Tags: java, maps, iteration

Ive created a map with keys of type integer and values are Sets of Strings. I have populated the map with some test data, and now need to write a method that prints out the contents of the map like "key: value, value, value"

Im assuming iterating through the map, and assigning the keys to a int variable and printing these out is how to start, but how would I then go about printing the values in the set of strings?

```
public class HandicapRecords {

    private Map<Integer, Set<String>> handicapMap;

    public HandicapRecords() {
        handicapMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void handicapMap() {
        Set<String> players = new HashSet<>();

        players.add("Michael");
        players.add("Roger"); 
        players.add("Toby");
        handicapMap.put(10, players);

        players = new HashSet<>();
        players.add("Bethany");
        players.add("Martin");
        handicapMap.put(16, players);

        players = new HashSet<>();
        players.add("Megan");
        players.add("Declan");
        handicapMap.put(4, players);
    }

    public void printMap() {
        //code for method to go here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate on a `Set` data structure just as you could in a list (well, actually list preserves the order, whereas the set does not but I presume that that would go beyond the scope of this question).

To print the data, you could do the following:

```
for (Integer num : handicapMap.keySet()) {
        System.out.print("Key : " + String.valueOf(num) + " Values:");
        for (String player : handicapMap.get(num)) {
            System.out.print(" " + player + " ");    
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You gave use nested for-each loop. We cant directly iterate through HashMao, take the keySet and print.
Example:

```
public void printMap()
{
 Set<Integer> keys=handicapMap.keySet();
 for(Integer k:keys)
 {
     Set<String> players=handicapMap.get(k);
     System.out.print(" "+k+":");
     int i=0;
     for(String p:players)
     {
         i++;
         System.out.print(p);
         if(i!=players.size())
             System.out.print(",");
     }
     System.out.println();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you won't know keys, so you have to iterate over all entries in hash map:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Set<String>> entry : handicapMap.entrySet())
{
    Integer key = entry.getKey();
    HashSet<String> values = entry.getValue();

    for (String s : values) { 
        // and now do what you need with your collection values
    }
}
```